# How can I visualize a series of points on a world map?

Tags: openstreetmap, visualisation, batch, linux, offline

I'd like to run a big list of IP addresses through geolocation and then display them on a map, most preferably an OpenStreetMap one. While geolocation will probably be easy using GeoIP, I'm looking for a free offline project that would allow me to visualise the GPS coordinates. How could I do that?

The platform I am interested in is Linux - it would be perfect if I could perform this task as a batch job so I could integrate it into my project: the input would be a list of GPS points, the output - an image showing hte map along with those points.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange.com What platform do you suppose to use? Mobile (Android/iOS) or a Desktop?

Comment: @dimitry.v.kiselev: Hello and thank you for the welcome - I just added the information you asked about.

Comment: Image as in "image file"? What format and resolution?

Comment: @bugmenot123: Yes, an image file or just data stream to stdout. I don't care about the format and resolution much.

Comment: Suitable suggestions really depend on a lot of factors. How many points, what detail do you want, do you want to show attributes, what scale, the whole world? As you want to batch this I'd go for gnuplot and NE unless you must use a detailed OSM background. Check out http://www.gnuplotting.org/mercator-projection/ and the posts linked within.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you consider "visualisation".

You can just use QGIS. Load the coordinates as separated text layer or whatever format you have. Then use the OpenLayers plugin to get a background OSM layer. Or if you actually do have world-wide data, better use Natural Earth vector data to show it in an appropriate projection.

http://qgis.org/

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/

There is a great example from @underdark how to do that via console.
http://anitagraser.com/2010/11/30/creating-high-resolution-images-using-qgis/

Comment: I would not have suggested QGIS if the question had specified the wish for "batch" jobs earlier. Yes, you can script it somehow but I would really not call it a good solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to display all data on the map (especially if you have more than 100 000 objects) as point.

In openlayers there are heatmap(http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) and cluster map (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/cluster.html). I recommend using one of them

In my software I create own "interpolation image" with data

Comment: That depends entirely on the purpose of the map. Heatmaps usually use terrible and misleading color maps, clustering usually ruins the visibility of spatial characteristics.